# Setting the colour for directories in Vim

Tags: vim

When I go into the Directory Listing in Vim the colour of files is nice and legible but directories are dark blue and impossible to read

I know this will change the colour to white, but I don't know what the [xyz] bit should be?

```
hi [xyz] ctermfg=white
```

Comment: First of all, are you properly setting your 'background' option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hi Directory gui=italic,bold guifg=Yellow guibg=Blue
```

Equally for the cterm (instead of the "gui" part)

Note that cterm supports only some colours.

So in your case

```
hi Directory ctermfg=White
```